# Open QWidget or QWindow from the current one

Tags: c++, qt

I know this was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004940/qt-how-to-open-several-windows-qwidgets-at-once), but it doesn't work...

Here's my problem: my program actually has 2 forms: `LoginWindow` and `MainWindow`, the programme starts on LoginWindow and then I called a class `Login` where are all methods and attributes for checking users
Here's some code:

```
//in LoginWindow class
Login log;
    log.checkID(ui->usrnmle->text().toStdString(), ui->passwdle->text().toStdString());

//in Login class
void Login::checkID(string usr, string passwd)
{
    if(usr == "Test" && passwd == "root")
    {
        cout << "Ok!" << endl;

        MainWindow mw = MainWindow();
        mw.show();

        LoginWindow lw = LoginWindow();
        lw.hide();

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connection failed " << endl;
    }
}
```

I type the good username and password, I got the 'Ok!' in the output console but MainWindow never appears.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainWindow mw` is a local variable that is destroyed as soon as you are out of `checkID` function (or even out of `if` but that does not really matters)

You need to create it on heap

```
MainWindow *mw =  new MainWindow();
mw->show();
```

Then to avoid memory leak you would need to destroy it when it is of no further use:

```
delete mw;
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not a native speaker, what do you make by "You need to create it on heap"?

Comment: @Newokmyne , it's a c++ basics about variables lifetime. When you create them like this `MainWindow mw = MainWindow();` they are created on a stack and they live until their scope ends. The variable created with new operator `MainWindow *mw =  new MainWindow();` lives until it is destroyed and is created on a heap.

Comment: Thanks. I am used to program with C# and the .NET Framework, this is my first QT program. I did as you said, now I can display the MainWindow, but the LoginWindow doesn't hide or close.
Anyway thanks

Comment: @Newokmyne it's the same issue - just create it as `LoginWindow* lw = new LoginWindow();` . But don't forget to delete them later, when you don't need these dialogs anymore (in destructor of main class for example)

Comment: No, once I am logged-in, the LoginWindow has to close and the MainWindow will work until the user close it. and about closing LoginWindow I found another way: `checkID(string usr, string passwd, LoginWindow *lw)` and then `{lw->close();}`... it works, I think this way is okay?

Comment: yes, but eventually you would still need to call `delete` on anything you have created with `new` call (except for Qt objects with parents, Qt will handle them myself). I would advise you to read a bit about `new` operator, since unlike in C#, C++ does not have built in garbage collector, you would need to clean up after yourself

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a QT developer, but

```
{
        cout << "Ok!" << endl;

    MainWindow mw = MainWindow();
    mw.show();

    LoginWindow lw = LoginWindow();
    lw.hide();
}
```

You are creating two **local** windows here, which are destroyed on the spot when the scope ends.

you need to keep these instances alive throught their use. for example, make them member variables of some bigger object like "App" class os so.